# R. Java file is not created in Android Application

Tags: java, android, compilation

`R.java` files are not being created in my project.

I have tried solutions like clean the project,removing `.jar` file from java build code.

Even though it is not working properly, how can I fix this?

Comment: try changing android OS version and again rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're either not using Eclipse, and/or not using the Android eclipse plugin.

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have not set android SDK  then download and set sdk target
2. Try to clean your project and try to get error which type of error you are getting and solve it
3. Try to create a new project from existing java, xml, menifest and drawables

Answer (score 0):

I think you are developing in Eclipse (java).
But you need to install the ADT Plugin (see here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

After that you must download the Android SDK ([Link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html))

In Eclipse you have to add the SDK.
Window->Preferences under Android -> SDK Location

Now create a new Android project or open an existing project like the API Demo.

The R.java file is generated automatically